# How to automatically download URL file from the Email link (downloadable/clickable content) with Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I have been struggling already for some weeks and I can't get it to work in Power Automate.
The issue is the following:

1. I am receiving in my Email (Monday morning) a bunch of system-generated emails that contain downloadable links:

That clickable link is in this form:
[https://deu01.test.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn1.test.co/XYZ/&%$!%&/§§abbvcccc](https://deu01.test.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn1.test.co/XYZ/&%$!%&/%C2%A7%C2%A7abbvcccc%C2%A0)  => (it is a long URL anyways)

[image]

The number of those Emails is like 10 with different names of course but the content inside them (after clicking on the link) is always .csv and always has the same structure.

2. What I wanted to accomplish is to automate that process, to get the content of those links and save them somewhere on SharePoint let's say under the same  I am unfortunately stuck on developing the proper actions/triggers in Power Automate to get this work.
3. We have Premium connectors!

This is my "work" up till now:

[image]

these are separate actions:

a)

[image]

b)

[image]

c)

[image]

d)

The error I usually get is on this step:
*The provided 'Http' action URI '*sanitized*' is not valid. The URI must be a well formed absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.*

[image]

e)

[image]

f)

[image]

I used this for the variable:

```
substring(  substring(outputs('html'), indexOf(outputs('html'), 
'https://deu01.test.outlook.com')),   0,  indexOf(substring(outputs('html'), 
indexOf(outputs('html'), 'https://deu01.test.outlook.com')), '"'))
```

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with this kind of flow, especially with HTTPS and so on. I saw something on Google but I don't get it properly...

Any kind of help would be appreciated!!

I was guided by this:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Automatically-download-a-file-that-is-in-an-url-link-inside-the/m-p/761142#M105122

Comment: It’s not that simple. You can’t always just take a url and download a file via HTTP like you would do if you pressed the button yourself. PowerAutomate desktop may be better for you. Far too hard to help if we can’t try it ourselves with your specific use case.

Comment: @Skin Yeah I can imagine, I was also thinking about Desktop version, but that is then different thing again... I thought it might be "simple".

Comment: See what you can achieve using Postman and that URL. If you can get the content of the file via Postman, you can do it in PowerAutomate as well.